# How to reference cells in range?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

Based on the text ("SNV") present in column L of the "HiddenSheet" worksheet, I would like to select and copy cells in columns 1 to 6 for all rows for which the "SNV" text is present in column L.

Then I would like to paste the values of the copied cells in the SNVReports worksheet.

```vb
Sub Macro2()

a = Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To a

    If Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Cells(i, 12).Value = "SNV" Then

        Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
        Worksheets("SNVReports").Activate
        b = Worksheets("SNVReports").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("SNVReports").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Activate

    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I sometimes receive:

> "Application-defined or object-defined error"

and it is apparently related to my range:

```vb
Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Cells(i,#)` references aren't qualified. So if the `SNVReports` tab is active when the macro runs, it's confused as to what range you're talking about.

The whole code could do with a tidy-up:

```
Sub Macro2a()

    Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastsourcerow as Long
    Dim lastdestrow as Long
    Dim i as Long

    Set sourcesheet = Worksheets("HiddenSheet")
    Set destsheet = Worksheets("SNVReports")

    With sourcesheet

        lastsourcerow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastsourcerow

            If .Cells(i, 12).Value = "SNV" Then
                lastdestrow = destsheet.Cells(destsheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
               .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 6)).Copy destsheet.Cells(lastdestrow + 1, 1)
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I completely missed that! Thanks a lot it works as intended now. And thank you for the code improvements, I will definitely use the source and destination sheets.